# How can I check the size of a collection within a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list in my Django template.  I want to do something only if the size of the list is greater than zero.

I have tried `myList|length` and `myList|length_is` but they have not been successful.

I've searched all over and don't see any examples. How can I check this?

Answer (score 381, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#if : just use, to reproduce their example:

```
{% if athlete_list %}
    Number of athletes: {{ athlete_list|length }}
{% else %}
    No athletes.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: |length I always get confused with jinja templating in Flask and with django. Thanks for the information. Really helpful.

Comment: The `length` filter also seems to work in conditional blocks. e.g. `{% if athlete_list|length > 1 %}...{% endif %}`

Comment: is there no inline (on lineI) option for that?

Answer (score 131):

If you're using a recent Django, [changelist 9530](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/9530) introduced an {% empty %} block, allowing you to write

```
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
  ...
{% empty %}
  No athletes
{% endfor %}
```

Useful when the something that you want to do involves special treatment for lists that might be empty.

Comment: Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty

Answer (score 28):

A list is considered to be `False` if it has no elements, so you can do something like this:

```
{% if mylist %}
    <p>I have a list!</p>
{% else %}
    <p>I don't have a list!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you tried myList|length and myList|length_is and its not getting desired results, then you should use `myList.count`

Comment: I'm shocked at how many upvotes this has... If `myList` is a `list` then this calls `list.count()` which raises an error that's masked in the template and gets treated as a false value.  The `count` method is to count the number of instances that match the passed in value.  However, this works if `myList` is a queryset.

Comment: Yes, for a collection `|length` can be used. For a QuerySet `.count` is adapted; you could use `exists` as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can try with:

```
{% if theList.object_list.count > 0 %}
    blah, blah...
{% else %}
    blah, blah....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is just for queryset but not for array length

Answer (score 9):

This works:

```
{% if myList|length %}
    Do something!
{% endif %}
```

Why there's so many answers here and why there's so much confusion is that this didn't always work.  I think at one point template filters couldn't be used on arguments to the `if` statement and this was later added.  It's also now possible to do things such as `{% if myList|length >= 3 %}`.  The filter should do the equivalent of `len(myList)` so any type of object that can handle that would also be able to handle the `|length` filter.

Comment: nice... had to use `{% if myList|length > 0 %}` (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Collection.count no bracket

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
{{wishlists.count}}
{% else %}0{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I need the collection length to decide whether I should render table `<thead></thead>`

but don't know why *@Django 2.1.7* the chosen answer will fail(empty) my `forloop` afterward.

I got to use `{% if forloop.first %} {% endif %}` to overcome:

```html
<table>
    {% for record in service_list %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>日期</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        {% endif %}
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ record.date }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```