# Checking the number of elements in an array in a Django template

Tags: django

I want to see if the number of elements in an array in my Django template is greater than 1. Can i use the following syntax for doing that ?

```
{% if {{myarr|length}} > 1 %}
<!-- printing some html here -->
{% endif %}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 92):

As of Django 1.2; **if** supports boolean operations and filters, so you can write this as:

```
{% if myarr|length > 1 %}
<!-- printing some html here -->
{% endif %}
```

See the Django Project [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#filters) for if with filters.

Comment: One curious thing: in 1.6 if you use spaces like `myarr | length`, django will print it, but if you try to compare, you get an error. To compare, I had to remove the spaces.

Comment: Note that you can use the same syntax to check `formset|length` like `{% if formset|length == 1 %}`

Answer (score 7):

no. but you can use [django-annoying](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/), and `{% if myarr|length > 1 %}` will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Sad, but there is no such functionality in django's 'if' tag. There is a [rumors that smarter if tag will be added in 1.2.](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Version1.2Features), at least it's in `High priority` list.

Alternatively you can use ["smart_if" tag from djangosnippets.com](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/)

OR you can add your own filter (same like length_is filter) - but it's just adding more useless code :(

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def length_gt(value, arg):
    """Returns a boolean of whether the value is greater than an argument."""
    try:
        return len(value) > int(arg)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return ''
length_gt.is_safe = False
register.filter(length_gt)
```

For more info consult [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags)

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those powers the Django template language doesn't give you.  You have a few options:

1. Compute this value in your view, and pass it into the template in a new variable.
2. Install an add-on library of template tags that lets you get richer comparisons, for example: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/
3. Use a different templating language altogether, if you think you'll be frequently running into templating language limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902034/how-can-i-check-the-size-of-a-collection-with-django-templates) will be of any help  ?

Checking collection sizes in Django templates is somewhat limited. The only solution that I was using, was passing another param from view to template - but to be honest, if depends from what You are trying to achieve.