# Django access the length of a list within a template

Tags: django, templates

Simple question. I have a list in my template and want to output the length of the list. Do I have to calculate this in my view and hand it over via my context?

```
<p>the size of the list is {{??}}</p>

{% for element in list %}
<p>element.Name</p>
{% end for %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Check the Size of a Collection with Django Templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902034/how-can-i-check-the-size-of-a-collection-with-django-templates)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Use [`length` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#length):

```
{{ some_list|length }}
```

Comment: This can be used for comparisons as well. For example:   ` {% if some_list|length == 1 %} do something ... {% endif %}`

Comment: Is that still OK? if the `some_list` is `[]` an empty list.

Answer (score 18):

Use `list|length`. `|` indicates that you will use a filter. The size of the list is

```
{{ list|length }}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
{% if your_list %}
{{ your_list|length }}
{% endif %}
```

Just remember that if your_list is a property it will be tigger on this line, so if you make dynamic list that is created each time you ask for it and you want to `for` later you will trigger it twice;

Answer (score 5):

Just a little update in case someone ends up here. As pointed in the comments, if you have a QuerySet, now it's possible to get the length with:

```
{{ your_list.count }}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Be careful, this only works with **QuerySet** as it calls their _count()_ method. [Python List count function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-function-count/) takes at least 1 argument to know what to count so it won't display anything in your template.

Comment: The count property only works on querysets as pointed out by @Benbb96. 

The template tag pointed out above by BigRetroMike works better.