# Length filter does not seem to be working

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following django template:

```
Mailing sent to {{ recipients|length }} recipient{{ recipients|pluralize }}.


<ul>
{% for r in recipients %}
  <li>{{ r }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This prints:

```
Mailing sent to  recipient.

<ul>
  <li>User x</li>
  <!-- snip -->
</ul>
```

`type(recipients)` returns list. `recipients` contains a bunch of database model instances.

It correctly prints the list with the `for`, but in the first line both filters return nothing at all. If I remove the filter it does print the `recipients` list. Why don't the filters work, and how do I fix it?

Recipients is constructed mainly like this:

```
recipients = (User.objects.filter(mailings_subscribed=True)
                           .exclude(email=''))
```

But is also constructed like this

```
recipients = [request.user]
```

Neither work as expected.

The solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902034/how-can-i-check-the-size-of-a-collection-with-django-templates) don't work.

Comment: Can you show that how do you query the `recipients`?

Comment: Updated the question with that.

Comment: the problem seems to be outside the code you posted here...